# Install catkin package from source (smach_tutorial)?

Tags: ros, catkin, tutorial, smach, catkin-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I'm having quite a bit of trouble understanding how to get a package installed via catkin. I am hoping to run through the smach tutorials - and this seems to necessitate install the smach_tutorial package. I've noticed that this package is not available via apt-get, I found the source and have checked it out with svn.

When trying to run catkin_make within the directory I am presented with:

"The specified base path "/home/frontier/catkin_ws/src/smach_tutorials/src" contains a CMakeLists.txt but "catkin_make" must be invoked in the root of workspace"

So I followed the ROS catkin tutorials, created a workspace, and created a package for the smach_tutorial. I then added the svn source to the src directory in this package and ran catkin_make install from my workspace. I was presented with:

```
"Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /home/frontier/catkin_ws/install/.catkin
-- Installing: /home/frontier/catkin_ws/install/_setup_util.py
-- Installing: /home/frontier/catkin_ws/install/env.sh
-- Installing: /home/frontier/catkin_ws/install/setup.bash
-- Installing: /home/frontier/catkin_ws/install/setup.sh
-- Installing: /home/frontier/catkin_ws/install/setup.zsh
-- Installing: /home/frontier/catkin_ws/install/.rosinstall
-- Up-to-date: /home/frontier/catkin_ws/install/etc/catkin/profile.d/05.catkin_make.bash
-- Up-to-date: /home/frontier/catkin_ws/install/etc/catkin/profile.d/05.catkin_make_isolated.bash
-- Installing: /home/frontier/catkin_ws/install/lib/pkgconfig/beginner_tutorials.pc
-- Installing: /home/frontier/catkin_ws/install/share/beginner_tutorials/cmake/beginner_tutorialsConfig.cmake
-- Installing: /home/frontier/catkin_ws/install/share/beginner_tutorials/cmake/beginner_tutorialsConfig-version.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/frontier/catkin_ws/install/share/beginner_tutorials/package.xml
-- Installing: /home/frontier/catkin_ws/install/lib/pkgconfig/smach_tutorials.pc
-- Installing: /home/frontier/catkin_ws/install/share/smach_tutorials/cmake/smach_tutorialsConfig.cmake
-- Installing: /home/frontier/catkin_ws/install/share/smach_tutorials/cmake/smach_tutorialsConfig-version.cmake
-- Installing: /home/frontier/catkin_ws/install/share/smach_tutorials/package.xml"
```

I feel as though there is something obvious that I am missing. Is there a good example on downloading the source for a catkin package and installing it?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/128331/install-catkin-package-from-source-(smach_tutorial)?/) by [jkretzmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11876/jkretzmer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-11**:
I'm not quite sure I understand the question. What are you expecting `catkin_make install` to do?

**Comment by [evk02](https://answers.ros.org/users/11636/evk02/) on 2014-02-11**:
It looks to me everything works just fine, based on the logs you referred you are installing smach_tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on your note about:

```
"The specified base path "/home/frontier/catkin_ws/src/smach_tutorials/src" contains a CMakeLists.txt but "catkin_make" must be invoked in the root of workspace"
```

I think you are executing catkin_make in the wrong directory, you should be in "/home/frontier/catkin_ws" when executing catkin_make.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0